# How to get real term_meta using ACF <5.0 with custom fields on taxonomy terms (instead of wp_options)

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

Having a simple Woocommerce site, I'm using ACF pro to add some custom fields to the terms of a given taxonomy. Using this, I can, for example, add a "color" field to my "product category" taxonomy terms. Good.

**The issue:**

Wanting to do some query using `get_terms()` ([codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)), I discovered that my `meta_query` parameters were not working (unexpected results). Why ? My custom fields were not saved (from backend) as `term_meta` but as `wp_option`.

It seems that ACF 4 is saving those fields, not as `term_meta` (as it's designed for), but as `wp_option`, in the Wordpress options table. So you cannot "query terms by `terms_meta`" (`meta_query`) using `get_terms()` ([codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)) to get some terms based on some `term_meta` value.

Comment: FYI, I'm using ACF 5.7 and the core is now using term_meta, so this whole issue is now mute.

Comment: Indeed, as I said in my answer, it seems ACF started supports of real term_meta starting from vers 5.x. So yes this issue is not relevant for actual versions but can be useful for platforms using old versions of ACF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this doing the following:

Let's say I have 2 custom fields on my taxonomy terms: `color` and `shape` (means I have a color and shape input on my backend terms edit/create page for the given taxonomy).

```
function acf_update_term_meta( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
    $term_id = (int) filter_var( $post_id, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
    if ( $term_id > 0 ) {
        update_term_meta( $term_id, $field['name'], $value );
    }

    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'acf/update_value/name=color', 'acf_update_term_meta', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'acf/update_value/name=shape', 'acf_update_term_meta', 10, 3 );

function acf_load_term_meta( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
    $term_id = (int) filter_var( $post_id, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
    if ( $term_id > 0 ) {
        $value = get_term_meta( $term_id, $field['name'], true );
    }

    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'acf/load_value/name=color', 'acf_load_term_meta', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'acf/load_value/name=shape', 'acf_load_term_meta', 10, 3 );
```

So we have:

- a filter to update the `term_meta` using `update_term_meta()` ([codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_term_meta/)) when updating this ACF fields (hooked 2 times, one for `color` and one for `shape`)
- a filter to return the `term_meta` value using `get_term_meta()` ([codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/)) instead of the `wp_option` (hooked 2 times, one for `color` and one for `shape`)

[source](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/how-to-use-wp-term-meta-on-acf-the-easy-way/)

***Note 1***:

this will trigger for ALL terms (no matter the taxonomy) having the `color` or `shape` custom field. You may need to filter by taxonomy if you don't want it to always apply in those fields cases.

***Note 2***:

[ACF5](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/upgrade-guide-version-5/) seems to support out-of-the-box real `term_meta`, but is still in early access only. 
The upgrade process seems to contain a refactor method for this particular case (duplicate data from `wp_options` to real `term_metas`):

> After updating to ACF 5, you will be prompted to upgrade the Database.
>
> This is a necessary step to migrate across your field and field group
>   settings from version 4.x. This upgrade will also copy across any
>   taxonomy term values from the 'wp_options' table to the 'wp_termmeta'
>   table.
>
> No data is deleted or modified during this upgrade. ([source](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/upgrade-guide-version-5/))

***Note 3***: I believe it would be possible to loop on all ACF terms custom fields to "generate" this code automatically for all custom fields on terms, and prevent having to add 2 filters for each new ACF term field. But as ACF5 should go out soon, it may not be worth the time.