# Can't get featured images added to custom taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, image, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to get a featured image option added to my custom taxonomy terms. I have initially tried using ACF to add an image, but this adds an image to the post type and not to the taxonomy.

For my second option I went through previous SO posts, but the answers are from a number of years ago and seem quite hacky.  The code below shows my current custom taxonomy setup. I added

```
/* custom taxonomies */
function my_custom_events_taxonomies(){

    register_taxonomy(
        'events',
        'events',
        array(
            'label' => 'Events type',
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'Events'),
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'custom-fields' => true,
        )

    );
    }
```

Comment: You need to add an image per taxonomy or per taxonomy terms ?

Comment: I need to add an image to the custom taxonomy terms. Just like when you can add an image to the categories in your category post section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an image field to a Taxonomy term using ACF.

Here I'm adding a custom ACF image field to the terms of the taxonomy 'Product tag' (a default taxonomy from Woocommerce, will work the same for all Taxonomy) (in your case it'll be the `events` taxonomy):

[image]

Then you get the new field when you create a new term for this Taxonomy (you also get the new image field on the term edit page of course):
[image]

I also invite you to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51990550/how-to-get-real-term-meta-using-acf-with-custom-fields-on-taxonomy-terms-instea/51990551#51990551) (mine) about how ACF4 manage custom fields on terms (fake `term_meta`). But in your case, where you just need to retrieve the image for a particular term somewhere, [ACF helpers](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/) should be enough.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work, but that was because I needed to change the "product_tag "to "events". Very helpful and thanks for the links also!

Comment: Yes I edited my answer to precise that in your case, it'll be the "events" taxonomy to select in the ACF location block. Glad you made it work!